# best parctises of placing objects on (uneven surfaces)

Tags: objects, import, scene

what is the easiest way of placing a car or a table on an uneven surface, I have downloaded a random car model from blender kit, it is in collection within a hierarchy of single meshes, I have found a great addon 'physics dropper', but it is a no go with raw import, I would have to join meshes of the model into one and drop that, that would work but that would also make a double polycount

how do you place such objects into a scene?

Comment: Is it a one time operation or do you intend to automatically position the car according to the terrain each frame?     If it is one time, you could position the wheels on the terrain and then constrain the vertical distance of the body to the wheels and parent everything else (all the other parts) to the body.

Comment: Hi, thank you, Just want to take imported model and drop it on the terrain without any edits to the imported model, I dont want to animate, Its just a simple scene, I have seen a great new plugin for animating cars, but its a paid overkill for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this should work then:

1. select the wheels and join them (CTRL+J)
2. select everything else from the car and parent it to the wheels (CTRL+P, object keep transform)
   [image: parent]
3. declare the wheels as a Rigid body in the Physics tab with default values
   [image: rigid body]
4. declare the ground as a Rigid body also, but select the "Passive" option instead of Active
5. Play the timeline (default SPACEBAR) and watch the car fall in place according to the terrain :)
   [image]

Comment: works, together with physics dropper addon like a charm, thank you much!